# The value of the property 'gatherItemInfo' is null or undefined, not a Function object

Tags: javascript

I've been researching this error for about an hour now with no progress.  I have a JavaScript function which builds a **span** element containing an *onclick* event.  But when I click on the span within IE11 to try to trigger the function, I instead get the error message shown above.  I suspect this might be a scoping issue, but could be wrong.

Here is the condensed section in question:

```
function getListItemsGeneric(branchId, listDispName) {
    $().SPServices({
        operation: "GetListItems",
        async: false,
        listName: listDispName,
        CAMLViewFields: "[FieldNames]",
        completefunc: function (xData, Status) {
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function() {
                [. . . other HTML-building code. . .]
                htmlBuilder += "<div class='editIcon'><span class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil' onclick=\"gatherItemInfo(" + progId + ", '" + listDispName + "')\"></span></div>";
            });
        }
    });
}

function gatherItemInfo(prog, list) {
    alert("!");
}
```

In building the **span**, I use the *onclick* event to call **gatherItemInfo** and provide two variables.  Clicking on the span should cause the alert to appear, but I instead get the message in this post's title.  **getListItemsGeneric** and **gatherItemInfo** are at the same level in the same JavaScript file; to my way of thinking the call should be able to look out and see **gatherItemInfo**, but this doesn't seem to be the case right now.

For what it's worth, it appears the **span** is well-formed when I look at it in the DOM Explorer.  What am I missing?

Comment: I've also tried moving gatherItemInfo into different levels of getListItemsGeneric in a vain effort to get something to happen, but still without success.

Comment: Please add more tags or explain what framework us using CAMLViewFields and SPFilterNode so we do not have to look that up

Comment: Have you tried to debug?

Comment: Have you tried adding `.toString()` to your variables `progId` and `listDispName`? This has worked in a similar looking situation.

Comment: just a concern.. i think its missing '' in progIDd should be - \"gatherItemInfo('" + progId + "', '" + listDispName + "')\"

Comment: @mplungjan, I'm using a couple different libraries to support this project: Marc Anderson's SPServices (https://spservices.codeplex.com/) and the span is pulling the icon from jQuery UI (http://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: @Neha, I've tried both ways-- wrapping progId in a single quote and not.  Both yield the same result, so I figured it would be a problem with where I've defined gatherItemInfo instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element's onclick value does not know the context in which the element was created. It's looking for the function `gatherItemInfo` in the global context. It sounds like you defined it somewhere else. You can either assign the click handler programmatically or make the function global.

Comment: I was thinking the same, but I have both defined in the same file.  In fact, I define gatherItemInfo directly after getListItemsGeneric, and they're both at the same level-- I'll modify the original post to better reflect this.

Comment: @AurumPotabile: The point of my answer is that the visibility of the two functions to each other *does not matter*. The onclick attribute is evaluated such that the function will be looked up in the window object. Are these functions defined on the window, or are they defined in a different scope?

Comment: I resolved it not long after your post-- the two functions were together within $(document).ready, but as soon as I moved gatherItemInfo out of $(document).ready, getListItemsGeneric was able to reach it.